# Android SQLite query stops AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I've debugged code and seems like sqlite query stops AsynkTask thread:

```
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Getting params");
Cursor c = null;
try {
  String[] queryParams = new String[]{String.valueOf(commandQueueId), String.valueOf(DIRECTION_OUT)};
  // ↓↓↓ STOPPING HERE ↓↓↓
  c = dataSource.query(TABLE_USER_COMMAND, "queue_id = ? AND direction = ? AND _id > " + fromId, queryParams);

  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "After query");
  if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    UserCommand command;
    do {
      // Something with cursor
    } while (c.moveToNext());
  }

} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error while querying", e);
} finally {
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Finnaly executed");
  if (null != c)
    c.close();
}
```

LogCat showing just "Getting params" string, then nothing (no errors or anything).
Code executed in AsyncTask, dataSource object have all methods synchronized. **In UI thread query works great.** What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

you are Not Passing Anything with `_id` inside your condition

```
"queue_id = ? AND direction = ? AND _id > "
```

it should be like

```
"queue_id = ? AND direction = ? AND _id > 1(or may other integer parameter)" + fromId, queryParams
```

Hope it will Help

Comment: Incorrect. I do pass _id param: ````" AND _id > " + fromId````. **fromId** is int. Besides i've tried pass it in params array. Same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to include the _id-parameter (fromId) in the query-String. So the query-function might not be able to build the query-String

```
"queue_id = ? AND direction = ? AND _id > " + fromId
```

Instead you should add your fromId to the selectionArgs (queryParams). Create a String-Array which contains your queryParams and the fromId. Then it should work.

```
String[] queryParams = new String[]{String.valueOf(commandQueueId), String.valueOf(DIRECTION_OUT), String.valueOf(fromId)};
c = dataSource.query(TABLE_USER_COMMAND, "queue_id = ? AND direction = ? AND _id > ? ", queryParams ); //queryParams which include your fromId
```

Comment: No difference. Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> dataSource object have all methods synchronized

Look out for dead locks!  Try synchronizing only your *writing* methods (insert, delete, update) and nor *reading* methods (query), as there is no risk to alter data while reading them
PS: I know question is a bit old, just in case others are reading it.